# Unmarshaler for HttpResonse Headers to T

Tags: scala, akka-http

Using Akka-http client:

what is a best way of extracting or Unmarshalling HttpResponse headers into a case class T? My current attempt:

class UnmarshallerSpec extends AkkaSpec("unmarshal") with ScalaFutures with WordSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll with BeforeAndAfterEach {

```
  import AmbryPostResponseUnmarshalling._
  import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling._

  case class AmbryPostFileResponse(ambryId: String)
  val ambryBlobInfo = new AmbryPostFileResponse("ambryId")



  val testHttpResponse = HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.OK, headers = List(Location("ambryId")))

  "Unmarshaler" should {
    "unmarshal" in {
      val result = Unmarshal(testHttpResponse).to[AmbryPostFileResponse]
      whenReady(result, timeout(10 seconds)) { r =>
        r shouldEqual ambryBlobInfo
      }
    }
  }

  object AmbryPostResponseUnmarshalling extends AmbryPostResponseUnmarshalling

  trait AmbryPostResponseUnmarshalling {
    implicit final val fru: FromResponseUnmarshaller[AmbryPostFileResponse] = {
      //  val h: Class[Location] = headers.Location.getClass[Location]
      def unmarshal(response: HttpResponse) =
        AmbryPostFileResponse(response.getHeader("Location").get.asInstanceOf[Location].uri.toString())

      Unmarshaller.strict(unmarshal)
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Could you please share more details about what you're trying to achieve? For example, some code examples of what you already tried usually greatly help other people understand the issue you're having.

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I improved it. My previous Unmarshaller attempt used java API which returned Optional causing all sorts of problems:

```
case class AmbryPostFileResponse(ambryId: String)

val ambryBlobInfo = new AmbryPostFileResponse("ambryId")

val testHttpResponse = HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.OK, headers
    = List(Location("ambryId")))

      "Unmarshaler" should {
        "unmarshal" in {
          val result = Unmarshal(testHttpResponse).to[AmbryPostFileResponse]
          whenReady(result, timeout(10 seconds)) { r =>
            r shouldEqual ambryBlobInfo
          }
        }   }

    implicit final val fromUploadResponse: FromResponseUnmarshaller[AmbryPostFileResponse] = {

      //  val h: Class[Location] = headers.Location.getClass[Location]   def unmarshal(response: HttpResponse) = {

        val locheader = response
          .headers
          .collect {
            case l:Location => l
          }
          .headOption
          .getOrElse(throw new NoSuchElementException("header not found: Location"))

        AmbryPostFileResponse(AmbryId(locheader.uri.toString))   }   Unmarshaller.strict(unmarshal) }
```